# How can I fix the, cookies always updating lifetime?

Tags: yii, yii2

Cookies are constantly updating lifetime in Yii2. How can I fix the problem?

When the method is called `Yii::$app->user->isGuest` cookies updates the time of his life.

I use base example and testing in browser **Google Chrome**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what You need, set this in configuration: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#$autoRenewCookie-detail